Survejs model - I am looking for complete object model for survey json
I am trying to implement the backend in c# for loading and saving surveys. I have seen the sample and it is using JSON string, is there documentation available for objects and properties that will help me build these c# objects?
I have tried to search in docs if there is complete object definition.

You can follow this tutorial to learn how to generate a client-side form JSON model based on your server-side C# object model definition: No-code Editor for Domain Models. The demo is available at Generate Domain Model Code.
